# Oracle.DataAccess.dll not in Visual Studio 2008 ".NET" reference list

Tags: oracle, visual-studio-2008, oracle10g, odp.net

I've got two Windows XP machines with both Visual Studio 2008 and Oracle Client 10.0.2.0.1 installed. One is a development machine and the other one a dedicated build machine. The machines were probably not set up the same way.

On my development machine, I've included Oracle.DataAccess.dll (version 10.2.0.1.100, *not the asp.net v 2.x one*) in a C# project. Note that the System.Data.OracleClient dll is insufficient (I don't properly remember why, I think it had something to do with bulk insertion/selection).
I was able to select that DLL from the `Project`->`Add Reference` dialog in the `.NET` tab.

Now on the build machine, I cannot build the project as it cannot find the .dll. The .dll is located in the same folder as on the development machine, (<installdir>\10.2.0\client_1\bin\Oracle.DataAccess.dll) in the same version.
The .dll is however not displayed in the `.NET` tab.

I tried (re)installing ODAC with ODP.Net for VS 2008 but it didn't change anything. When looking at the registry, I realized that my Development machine had a registry folder

> [HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SOFTWARE\Microsoft.NETFramework\AssemblyFolders\ODP.Net]

which points to the bin directory of my oracle installation. This entry does not exist on the build machine. Unfortunately, manually adding the key did not make Visual Studio find it (I've tried rebooting).

My main question is: 
**What do I have to do so the Build Machine automatically finds the Oracle.DataAccess.dll?** 
(*Note: manually adding the .dll each time the solution is changed would work, but that is not an option*).

You can maybe help me out already by answering one of the following subquestions:

- Which installer sets that registry entry?
- Do I maybe have to reinstall the whole Oracle Client in a different configuration? (e.g. ADMIN)
- Do I need more than just the Oracle Client, ODAC and .NET installed?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I managed to resolve the issue by completely uninstalling the Oracle Client on the build machine, then doing a fresh installation using the `Administrator` configuration rather than the `Developer` configuration.

Note that installing the `Administrator` configuration on top of the existing oracle installation did not work.